# wp-plugin for applying Rss Feed only to pages

Tags: wordpress, rss

I want to apply Rss Feeds to my pages,not posts(as my posts are not working properly) as a temporary solution to my project.

Wp-Plugin or code,anything will be work for my wordpress site.

I applied this codes@

```
<div class="left mr15"><a class="ico_rss" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" title="RSS"><span>RSS</span></a></div>
```

It showed only my recent posts,but I want to show my recent pages.

Your suggestion are appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a RSS to Page plugin for WordPress .

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss-in-page/

Comment: How can i apply this plugin to my template page

Answer (score 0):

1. I created my own Rss feed for pages and got it working for my pages
   only,not posts.

   $numposts = 5;

   function yoast_rss_date( $timestamp = null ) {
     $timestamp = ($timestamp==null) ? time() : $timestamp;
     echo date(DATE_RSS, $timestamp);
   }

   function yoast_rss_text_limit($string, $length, $replacer = '...') { 
     $string = strip_tags($string);
     if(strlen($string) > $length) 
       return (preg_match('/^(.*)\W.*$/', substr($string, 0, $length+1), $matches) ? $matches[1] : substr($string, 0, $length)) . $replacer;
     return $string; 
   }
   $numpages = 5; // how many recently modified Pages to display
   $pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type='page' and post_status='publish' and post_title != 'Rss' ORDER BY post_modified DESC LIMIT $numpages"); 
   $lastpost = $numposts - 1;

   header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8");
   echo '';
   ?>

     Clayton Updates
     http://vygears.com/Clayton1/
     The latest blog pages from Clayton
     en-us
     post_date_gmt) ); ?>
     post_date_gmt) ); ?>

       
     
       ID); ?>
       ID); ?>
       post_content, 500).'
   Keep on reading: ID).'">'.get_the_title($page->ID).''.']]>';  ?>
       post_date_gmt) ); ?>
       ID); ?>
2. Save the above code as Rss.php in your website folder(along with index.php,header.php,....) as template page.
3. Then,open the admin dashboard and go to Pages->New Page and in title give "Rss" and in right side under Template,select "Custom Feed_trial" and click publish.
4. Then,apply your Rss page path(eg. website address/?page_id=2022) to the Rss button which you have in your website or blog.